# How do I make sure TFS is using most recent Azure SDK?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-roles

I have a Visual Studio 2013/Azure SDK 2.3 solution with a WebRole ccproj project where I am trying to automate the build and packaging to a .cspkg file.

If I build the solution on my dev machine and then right-click project and do "Package" (with Cloud/Release) everything works fine.

However, on the TFS Build Controller machine, I get the following error:

```
C:\Builds\439\MyPortal\Dev-MyPortal\bin\Debug\ServiceDefinition.csdef: Cannot find the physical directory 'C:\Builds\439\MyPortal\MyGateway' for virtual path MyGateway/.
```

This seems to indicate that the TFS build server is using the old Azure SDK 1.7 (and before) behavior for site physicalDirectory declarations:

```
<Site name="SolovisPortal" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\SolovisPortal">
```

I have the above definition in my ServiceDefinition.csdef. Another problem is that it looks like the ServiceDefinition.csdef is being overwritten into the same place for all 4 of my ccproj projects in the Solution.

Note: The build works fine if I eliminate "/t:Publish /p:TargetProfile=Cloud" from the MSBuild arguments.

Really, all I want to do is create the cspkg file for 2 of the 4 ccproj in the solution (just want to "Package" as opposed to "Publish").

**Update (4/9/2014)**
I am able to build the Azure package from a command-line on my local machine using cspack:

```
cspack MyPortalAzure\bin\Release\ServiceDefinition.csdef /out:test.cspkg /useCtpPackageFormat
```

However, my cspkg is 18MB, but it I manually "Package" the cspkg through Visual Studio it is only 15MB. Is VS doing something special to compress the file?

Comment: I believe you are using Hosted Build servers. If yes, as per the link below Windows Azure SDK 2.2 is installed on the hosted build servers. http://listofsoftwareontfshostedbuildserver.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: I'm using a local Build Controller. I installed Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Azure SDK 2.3 on the Build Controller. It sort of looks like part of the problem is that TFS is trying to package the files that have been collapsed into the single output folder. I'm currently looking into calling cspack from a post-build step (if a custom variable that I set is present).

Comment: I am able to build the cspack file from the command-line, but it appears that the cspkg file I produce is 18MB, but the one created by manually packaging the project through VS2013 is 15MB. Is Visual Studio doing something special to compress the file?

Comment: Is there a way to withdraw the question or rename it? It's clear now that the version of Azure SDK on TFS is not the issue. The issue seems to be that getting cspkg files to automatically build in both Visual Studio and TFS requires more than a fair bit of msbuild/csproj/ccproj hackery.